# Post File to PHP File XMLHttpRequest Object Return Data Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to pass an image file using ajax post method to a php file. The script sends the object, but my parser doesn't get the $_FILES["avatar"]["name"] and the tmp_name. Is there a way to send the file via AJAX like a form would do?

My HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="avatar_file" name="avatar" />
<input type="file" id="title_file" name="title" />
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" id="save_changer" value="Submit Data" onclick="subForm();">
```

My Javascript:

```
function subForm(){
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "php_parsers/photo_system.php";
var fn = document.getElementById("avatar_file").files[0];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("avatar", fn);
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        alert(fn);
    }
}
hr.send(formData);
}
```

And my PHP Parser (php_parsers/photo_system.php):

```
if (isset($_FILES["avatar"]["name"]) && $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
$fileName = $_FILES["avatar"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
$fileType = $_FILES["avatar"]["type"];
$fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["avatar"]["error"];
```

Comment: How is the form tag looking? Did your recognize the enctype attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

from your code and try again

Comment: Please edit the answer to include what you think removing this line will do. Code or changes without explanation is less useful.